# Can't redirect to custom report from community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, redirect, custom-reports

I have a lightning component that redirects to custom reports including filters if needed and it's included inside one of our salesforce communities.

The issue is that the generated URL works fine with my Admin user but stops working if it's called from the community.

Community user has read access to the report folder and also has record access to the report.

This is an example of my generated url:

**/lightning/r/Report/00O7E000000rwNXUAY/view?queryScope=userFolders&fv0=FirstFilter**

And this is working fine as a System Administrator but no matter what I try it doesn't work with this kind of user.

**Could it be something with the community prefix in the URL?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know if the field in the report are allowed for the community user to view. I mean read access atleast.

Comment: What happens when community user access it?